# Are statements x=x+1 and x++ considered atomic?

Tags: c, atomic

A statement is considered atomic if there is at most 1 reference to a shared variable.

Let's say that variable x is a shared variable.

> Statement 1: x = x + 1;

Statement 1 has two references, but they are to the same variable. Does this still count as "two references"?

> Statement 2: x++;

Statement 2 does the same as statement 1 but there is only one reference.

So are these statements considered atomic or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which language?

Comment: C. Does it matter what language it is?

Comment: Some languages may cache the variable in stack/registers and some languages allow operator overloading

Comment: maybe see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic ? If x is of type `int`, then `x++` is not atomic. But `atomic_int` can be used instead

Comment: @Daniele According to the website, both statements are non-atomic. Thanks, that was exacly what I was looking for!

Comment: *A statement is considered atomic if there is at most 1 reference to a shared variable.*  That is **NOT** sufficient to guarantee atomic access.  Just because your code only reads a value once doesn't mean that read is guaranteed to be atomic.  If another thread updates the value at the same time, you may get a result that is a mix of the pre- and post-write content.

Answer (score 2):

The premise of your question:

> A statement is considered atomic if there is at most 1 reference to a shared variable.

is not something that comes out of or is in agreement with the semantics of the C lanaguage. If you want to define "atomic" to mean something totally different than what it normally means in C, using this definition, then by the plain english meaning of "reference" I would interpret the first statement to be "non-atomic" and the second to be "atomic". But this has nothing to do with the usual meaning of atomic, and neither of them is atomic in the sense of atomicity with respect to asynchronous interruption (signals/interrupt handlers) or memory synchronization with other threads/processes/cores.